# Regular expression to check if the URL is home URL or not

Tags: javascript, regex, url

I am looking for a regular expression to check if the URL is home URL or not.

**Valid**

```
http://example.com
https://example1.com
https://example2.com/
http://anything.com/?test=12
http://anything.com?test=12
```

**Invalid**

```
http://example.com/path
https://example.com/path1/path2
https://example.com/path1?test=123
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/^https?:\/\/[^\/]+\/?(\?.*)?$/gm
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zK4tD0/1)